# Nginx Reverse Proxy SSL Error

Tags: nginx

So I have my Nginx reverse proxy set up as follows.

```
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.net;
    return 301 https://mydomain.net$request_uri;
    }
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.net;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/privkey.pem;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://myip:myport;
    }
}


But when I try to connect to my website it says "This site can't provide a secure connection, ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. Did I misconfigure SSL?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the listen directive to listen *with the **SSL** protocol*: `listen 80;` says to listen for `http` connections on port 80, but `listen 443 ssl;` says to listen on port 443 for `https` connections.

the configuration should be as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.net;
    return 301 https://mydomain.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.net;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myip:myport;
    }
}
```

you can also combine them. you can remove your return statement, and combine all others into one server block. just add this snippet:

```
  if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$host$uri?$args;
  }
```